# How to disable alert messages using ChromeDriverManager?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I am using following library for Web driver management. 
I want to disable all the browser alert messages while my test run. Can someone help how to disable alerts using that library? or any workaround ?

```js
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;
```

Comment: Why are you not using Selenium?

Comment: This library is easy to use. I do not need to individually download the chrome driver and setup all the path. This library will take care of all things.

Comment: The library doesn't handle that, you need to use the driver that you create and handle the alert

Answer (score 1):

JavascriptExecutor worked for me. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert. once you set it, it will apply for the whole session

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked

Hope it will help you :)